# Is it necessary to stop all python scripts when upgrading python packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

If a python script using package X is running and package X is being upgraded, will it lead to permission problem that will cause the upgrade to fail?

I am using Windows 10, Anaconda v5.2 running on python v3.6 and conda to do update of packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although pure Python files are compiled in memory when imported, and the source is (almost) no longer relevant after that, that's not the end of the story.

Packages may have extra assets that are lazily loaded, or your program or its dependencies may load dependent modules on demand, so, if running during an upgrade, it may load unexpected versions of packages/resources, or even halfway-upgraded packages.

Also, native (=non Python-only) modules - .pyd files on Windows - are dlls that are loaded in the importing process. As dlls are mapped in memory with no sharing, replacing them while they are loaded is not allowed, so this may block the upgrade of the relevant packages.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a simple test just now. I ran a python script which loops forever. It uses numpy. Then, I tried to install a python package(pytorch) that requires downgrading the numpy version. When the script is running, the installation failed with some "no permission" error message. After I stopped the script, the installation succeeded.

Based on the results of this experiment, the conclusion is that it is recommended to stop all python scripts when performing python package upgrade.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Answer (score 1):

When you `import`, you're creating a local instance of the package in your RAM for running. So upgrading your packages should not affect your scripts running.
You can look at `from importlib import reload` to reload your packages while your scripts are still running